# The bottom SystemUiOverlay status bar is not hidden properly

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to disable the top and bottom status bars using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays`, which in itself is working as expected.

However, the bottom bar does not *"disappear"* correctly. Sure, it removes the actual native android navigation buttons, but it does not however remove the space used by the buttons.

I've attached a screen shot below.

Has anyone encountered something like this and is able to shed some light on it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>There is not fix for this as of right now. This is simply a limitation of flutter as the time of writing.</strike>

*As per:* https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14432

> When status bar is hidden, app bar's height remains the same #14432

It should be noted that this only seems to affect portrait mode. Landscape mode seems to have no issue with this.

This should be working fine for Android as of this [PR](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/6282).

It is unclear whether it works for iOS or not.

> flutter/engine#6282 fixes this problem for Android. A similar fix for iOS should exist and I will look into it.
>
> I was informed that the iOS bug was fixed recently. Is anyone still having issues with the iOS top padding?